# Live search using codeigniter Json Mysql Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am doing a project on Live Search Using Jquery Ajax, Php Codeigniter and Mysql
This search is similar to 
http://w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp but with MYSql

Here is my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ix08s_subjects` (
  `SUB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(211) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SUB_ID`),
  KEY `FK_ix08s_subjects` (`added_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='to store the subjects' AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `ix08s_subjects`

```
INSERT INTO `ix08s_subjects` (`SUB_ID`, `NAME`, `added_by`, `date_added`) VALUES
(1, 'physics', 2, '2013-05-31 10:07:55'),
(2, 'physics', 2, '2013-05-31 10:41:09');
```

Here is my model code-
Subjectmodel.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Subjectmodel extends CI_Model {
   public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function getSubject($search){
        $this->db->select("SUB_ID,NAME");
        $whereCondition = array('NAME' =>$search);
        $this->db->where($whereCondition);
        $this->db->from('ix08s_subjects');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my Controller code-
Subject.php

```
<?php
class Subject extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('SubjectModel');
    }
    public function index(){
        $search=  $this->input->post('search');
        $query = $this->SubjectModel->getSubject($search);
        echo json_encode ($query);
        $this->load->view('search', $query);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my View code-
Search.php

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://somexyz/js/javascripts/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somexyz/js/javascripts/plugin/json2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#search").keyup(function(){
        if($("#search").val().length>3){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/ibps/index.php/subject",
            cache: false,               
            data:'search='+$("#search").val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $('#finalResult').html("");
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                if(obj.length>0){
                    try{
                        var items=[];   
                        $.each(obj, function(i,val){                                            
                            items.push($('<li/>').text(val.NAME));
                        }); 
                        $('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
                    }catch(e) {     
                        alert('Exception while request..');
                    }       
                }else{
                    $('#finalResult').html($('<li/>').text("No Data Found"));       
                }       

            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
        });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
<ul id="finalResult"></ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When ever I type four letters into the search box I get this alert pop up

Error while request..

Not getting the values from the database

Comment: `error while request....` get the actual error details by seeing in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the returned format of `http://localhost/ibps/index.php/subject`.

You have added the line:

```
$this->load->view('search', $query);
```

When compaired to your previous question '[Live search using Codeigniter Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850847/live-search-using-codeigniter-mysql)'. This is probably adding an html template to the output and not the `json` expected by the ajax call.

Have a look at [Return JSON with CodeIgniter](http://rogue-systems.com/2013/01/711-return-json-with-codeigniter/)

Comment: If I remove it I Don't see any search box in my output at all @James Birkett

Comment: The output of `http://localhost/ibps/index.php/subject` should not contain any html when used in the ajax call as the responce must be json.